# Find a where start and end date are not null over multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

To keep it simple I have one table.  One column is a lotnumber, one is a start date and one is a finish date.  When the first entry for a lot number is enter it has a start date.  Depending on how many shift it takes to finish the lot I can then have server rows with no date until it is completed and then I have a finish date.

SHIFT.........Lot..........Start..........End 
1...................1............O.............Null 
2...................1..........      Null.........   Null 
3..................         1..........      Null..........   O    
1..................        2...........      O...........      Null

I want to pick out the lot number that has both a start and end date even though they are not on the same row.  Is that possible.

SELECT t1.LotNumber
From BlendingCycleTime t1
INNER JOIN BlendingCycleTime t2
ON t1.LotNumber = t2.LotNumber
WHERE t1.ActualStartDayTime IS NOT NULL AND t2.ActualFinishDayTime IS NULL

I have landed on this but it doesn't really work too well.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table #tb (Shift int,lot int,StartD int, endD int)
go
insert into #tb values(1,1,0,null),
                      (2,1,null,null),               
                      (3,1,null,0),               
                      (1,2,0,null)

select * from #tb

select Lot
from #tb
group by Lot
Having Max(startD) is not null and Max(endD) is not null
```